# JAVA Rest service jersey returnin 404

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Hi I followed vogella tutorial and made some changes according to my requirements. when I tried to call the service after deploying the application to the server I am getting 404 (Not found) error in rest client/browser. Please help and tell me whats wrong in the code.

Here are my fiels

Web.XML

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>UploadDemo</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.services.demo</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name>
    <param-value>
     c:\data\
 </param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

Java Class

```
package com.services.demo;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/demo")
public class ServiceDemo {

@GET
@Path("/hello")
public String getMessage() {
    return "Hello world";
}


}
```

Application structure:
[image: Application structure]

And the URL I am calling is

http://localhost:8080/uploadDemo/demo/hello

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions in the logs ?

Comment: What is the deployed war name that resides inside tomcat\webapps folder.

Comment: I am running application through eclipse. There is no war file in webapps folder of tomcat.

Comment: You can find the deployed application inside your workspace `yourworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`

Answer (score 2):

If you are not getting any other exceptions on the server side but still getting a 404 error, then the problem is with the url.

http://localhost:8080/uploadDemo/demo/hello

Your url looks wrong and it should be:

http://localhost:8080/UploadDemo/demo/hello

I guess your war name deployed in your container will be **"UploadDemo"** (by looking at your folder structure) instead of **"uploadDemo"**.

Comment: One more question. Now I am not able to access xyz.jsp or any html page. Is there any modification needed in web.xml folder to support both Web project and rest services ? Can you provide me web.xml

Comment: You don't have to do anything different to support rest in your web project. All you have to do is add the required jars and register the rest controller in your web.xml

Comment: How do you access your pages(url) xyz.jsp?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/UploadDemo/xyz.jsp , It is running if i removed all the Rest services related code from web.xml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76325/discussion-between-balaji-and-viral-thakker).